# Use SimpleXML annotations for documentation

Tags: java, simple-framework

I'm currently designing a XML communication protocol. I did this by creating the classes and using the appropriate annotations. Now I came to the need to have some kind of documentation that can be understood without any idea how Simple works. For example a DTD or a XML Schema file.

Is there any tool available to do this?

Regards
Max

Answer (score -1):

See [Tutorial](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php) or the [Examples](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/examples/examples.php) or the [Javadoc](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/), there should be enough information there to be able to understand it.

Comment: ?! My question was how to create a XSD file by using my Java class hierarchy! I did not find any note to this on Simple's website!?